# Summarise data table columns by name

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table where many of the variables have been split into a positive and negative component. I'd like to combine these columns so that the signed value of the variable is present. (Such variables always have `positive` and `negative` in the names, and no other variables do. However, the `positive` and `negative` substrings may occur at any position in the variable -- *i.e.* only `grepl("(positive)|(negative)", names(dt))` correctly identifies them.)

For example,

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)

(DT <- data.table(x = 1:5, 
                  a_positive = sample(1:5), 
                  a_negative = sample(1:5), 
                  b_positive = sample(1:5), 
                  b_negative = sample(1:5), 
                  c_normal = sample(1:5)))

   x a_positive a_negative b_positive b_negative c_normal
1: 1          2          5          2          3        5
2: 2          5          4          1          5        1
3: 3          4          2          3          4        2
4: 4          3          3          4          1        4
5: 5          1          1          5          2        3
```

Intended result:

```
   x c_normal  a  b
1: 1        5 -3 -1
2: 2        1  1 -4
3: 3        2  2 -1
4: 4        4  0  3
5: 5        3  0  3
```

My way of doing it relies on a `for` loop and `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lazyeval)
library(magrittr) 

unite_positive_negative <- function(dt){
  signed_names <- 
    names(dt)[
      duplicated(gsub("(positive)|(negative)", "", names(dt))) | 
        duplicated(gsub("(positive)|(negative)", "", names(dt)), fromLast = TRUE)]

  unsigned_names <- 
    gsub("_*((positive)|(negative))_*", "", signed_names)

  the_names <- 
    data.table(signed_names = signed_names, 
               unsigned_names = unsigned_names) 

  for (unsigned_name in unsigned_names){
    poz <- the_names[unsigned_names == unsigned_name & grepl("positive", signed_names, fixed = TRUE)][["signed_names"]]
    neg <- the_names[unsigned_names == unsigned_name & grepl("negative", signed_names, fixed = TRUE)][["signed_names"]]

    dt %<>%
      mutate_(.dots = setNames(list(interp(~p - n, p = as.name(poz), n = as.name(neg))), unsigned_name)) 
  }

  # Unimportant
  unselect_ <- function(.data, .dots){
    all_names <- names(.data)
    keeps <- names(.data)[!names(.data) %in% .dots]
    dplyr::select_(.data, .dots = keeps)
  }

  dt %>%
    unselect_(.dots = signed_names)
}
```

Is there a pure `data.table` way? (Or a more direct way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try with `melt/dcast`.  Reshape the dataset from 'wide' to 'long' format with `melt` specifying the `id.var` as the 'x' and 'c_normal' columns (if there are many 'normal' columns, we can also use `grep` to get this straight.  Split the 'variable' column into two using `tstrsplit`.  Grouped by 'x', 'c_normal' and 'var1' (from the `split`), we subset the "negative" and "positive" of 'value', multiply them with `-1/1` and add them together.  Then, `dcast` from 'long' to 'wide' format.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(DT, id.var = c("x", "c_normal"))[, 
       c("var1", "var2") := tstrsplit(variable, "_")
        ][, -1*value[var2=="negative"] + value[var2=="positive"] ,
        by = .(x, c_normal, var1)],
              x + c_normal~var1, value.var="V1")
#   x c_normal  a  b
#1: 1        5 -3 -1
#2: 2        1  1 -4
#3: 3        2  2 -1
#4: 4        4  0  3
#5: 5        3  0  3
```

---

Another option without the `melt/dcast` would be to subset the dataset for "positive" and "negative" columns (assuming that they are ordered), multiply by `1/-1`, do the addition (`+`) and assign those output to the subset of dataset without the "positive/negative" columns.

```
DT1 <- DT[, c("x", grep("normal", names(DT), value=TRUE)), with = FALSE]
DT2 <- DT[, grep("positive", names(DT)), with = FALSE] +
          -1 * DT[, grep("negative", names(DT)), with = FALSE]
DT1[, c("a", "b") := DT2]
DT1
#    x c_normal  a  b
# 1: 1        5 -3 -1
# 2: 2        1  1 -4
# 3: 3        2  2 -1
# 4: 4        4  0  3
# 5: 5        3  0  3
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, but a variable is an 'unsigned' column *if and only if* it contains the substrings `positive` or `negative`.  So not all 'normal' columns may contain `normal`, and the `positive` and `negative` may occur anywhere in the column name.

Comment: @Hugh My solutions were based on the example you provided and both of them works for that example.